# How do I make Visual Studio update a Windows Store App, not replace it

Tags: debugging, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio project for a Windows Store app written in C#. I want to test the app in a situation where a user updates from one version to another, but I can't. When I try to debug my app in Visual Studio, I get this message:

> The app xxx is already installed on this machine.
>   If you continue with the current deployment, the existing app will be uninstalled and the app's current state will be deleted.

I don't want to lose the existing state of the app because I wrote code to find the old version of some data and to update it.

Installing the previous version from the Windows Store, or from a side-load, both have the same effect. I can't then test the new version in Visual Studio.

Does anyone know a way to get Visual Studio to not delete the old version, and install the new version from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the version from the Store. Simply deployy the app from Visual Studio (via debug). 
To test

1. Set the version number to a previous number
2. Deploy the app
3. Use the app
4. Change app version number
5. Deploy the app
6. Use the app

Step 6 is where you will notice the app has been updated.

Comment: It is not the version number that needs to be old, it is the actual data created by the app. I need to run a copy of the old app that creates data in an old format, then run the new version to test its ability to convert that data to the new format.

I can run the old app and save the data. then after running the old app, replacing that old one, I can kill it, copy the data from the old app into the app local storage, and then start the new app again. it sees the old data and tries to convert it.

I would rather not copy data like this, since it doesn't match what happens during an update.

Comment: The steps above are the same. Use code from last week (or whenever you made the change) run the app, then use the new code. For testing purposes, you can even have an if statement if(version < 2) OldCode(); else NewCode(); After testing, remove Oldcode

Comment: Thanks. My question was about how to specifically use the app that is installed from the Store, but that is obviously not possible. I can simulate that without having to use old source files, by saving the localstate directory of the Store installed version and then copying it over the localstate directory of a new install. The app will start and see all of the old data as if it had replaced the old version. Sorry that I misunderstood what you meant by "set the version number to a previous number" since that now clearly suggests using all of the older source files.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but there is another way to do this.

1. install the old version
2. use the app to generate the data you want to test
3. Copy the LocalState directory from C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\APPNAME
4. Do not close the app
5. run the new app from Visual Studio
6. Say yes to the prompt about removing the old app and data
7. Kill the app at the first screen
8. Copy the old LocalState dir back into the Packages dir
9. Run the app from VisualStudio